# onTextRecognized front camera app crash without log React Native android

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-camera

I have switched from back camera to front camera, React native camera but it will crash without any log. Here is the following code.

```
 <RNCamera
                          ref={ref}
                            autoFocus={RNCamera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}
                         
                            type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
                            androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
                                title: 'Permission to use camera',
                                message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
                                buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                                buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                            }}

                            onTextRecognized={({textBlocks})=>{console.log(textBlocks)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Facing same issue. Whenever I open camera and the line

```
onTextRecognized={({textBlocks})=>{console.log("textBlocks===", textBlocks)}}
```

craches the app. without showing any error in logs. Whenever I comment this line . App works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
```

to

```
missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'mlkit'
```

in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

you have set additional setup for text and face recognition
https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/installation.md#requirements
this woks for me!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35348598)